# ipython debugger: full traceback on interactive pdb?

Tags: python, ipython, pdb, ipdb

I recently switched from ipython0.10 to ipython0.11.  In ipython0.11, I only see a small snippet of the full traceback when the python debugger engages (i.e. using `%pdb`), whereas in ipython0.10 I'd see the full traceback.  As far as I can tell, the full traceback is not directly accessible from the pdb command line - you can navigate through it with 'u' but can't see it directly.

So, is there any way to show the full traceback?  Such as a configuration parameter?

Or, even more usefully, is there any way to have ipython just show the Exception that was caught, rather than showing where in the code it was caught?

EDIT:  Example:

```
In [1]: pdb
Automatic pdb calling has been turned ON

In [2]: 1/0
> <ipython-input-2-05c9758a9c21>(1)<module>()
     -1 1/0

ipdb> q
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/adam/<ipython-input-2-05c9758a9c21> in <module>()
----> 1 1/0

ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

I'd like to see the ZeroDivisionError *before* `q`'ing out of the pdb.

Comment: This is a bug in IPython 0.11 - the traceback is printed after you leave the debugger, rather than before it starts. It will be fixed for 0.12 (which should be out before Christmas).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is there any way to have ipython just show the Exception that was
>   caught, rather than showing where in the code it was caught?

You could use [`sys.excepthook`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html):

```
import sys

def exc_hook(type, value, traceback):
    print type

sys.excepthook = exc_hook
```

From the [`sys` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html):

> `sys.excepthook(type, value, traceback)`
>
> This function prints out a given traceback and exception to
>   sys.stderr.
>
> When an exception is raised and uncaught, the interpreter calls
>   sys.excepthook with three arguments, the exception class, exception
>   instance, and a traceback object. In an interactive session this
>   happens just before control is returned to the prompt; in a Python
>   program this happens just before the program exits. The handling of
>   such top-level exceptions can be customized by assigning another
>   three-argument function to `sys.excepthook`.
>
> `sys.__displayhook__`
>   `sys.__excepthook__`
>
> These objects contain the original values of displayhook and
>   excepthook at the start of the program. They are saved so that
>   displayhook and excepthook can be restored in case they happen to get
>   replaced with broken objects.

---

You can also try starting ipython with the `--xmode` option set to `Plain`

From [IPython reference](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/reference.html):

> ```
> $ ipython [options] files
>
> --xmode=<modename>
> ```
>
> Mode for exception reporting.
>
> Valid modes: Plain, Context and Verbose.
>
> **Plain**: similar to python’s normal traceback printing.
>
> **Context**: prints 5 lines of context source code around each line in the traceback.
>
> **Verbose**: similar to Context, but additionally prints the variables currently visible where the exception happened (shortening their
>   strings if too long). This can potentially be very slow, if you happen
>   to have a huge data structure whose string representation is complex
>   to compute. Your computer may appear to freeze for a while with cpu
>   usage at 100%. If this occurs, you can cancel the traceback with
>   Ctrl-C (maybe hitting it more than once).

Here are some example usages.  Notice the difference in lines for each traceback:

**`--xmode=Plain`**:

```
[ 19:55 jon@hozbox ~/SO/python ]$ ipython --xmode=Plain ipython-debugger-full-traceback-on-interactive-pdb.py 
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ipython-debugger-full-traceback-on-interactive-pdb.py", line 2, in <module>
    1 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

**`--xmode=Context`**:

```
[ 19:55 jon@hozbox ~/SO/python ]$ ipython --xmode=Context ipython-debugger-full-traceback-on-interactive-pdb.py 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/jon/SO/python/ipython-debugger-full-traceback-on-interactive-pdb.py in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 #!/usr/bin/python
      3 1 / 0
      4 
      5 

ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

**`--xmode=Verbose`**:

```
[ 19:54 jon@hozbox ~/SO/python ]$ ipython --xmode=Verbose ipython-debugger-full-traceback-on-interactive-pdb.py 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/jon/SO/python/ipython-debugger-full-traceback-on-interactive-pdb.py in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 #!/usr/bin/python
      3 1 / 0
      4 
      5 

ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

And without specifying a .py file:

**`--xmode=Plain`**:

```
[ 19:55 jon@hozbox ~/SO/python ]$ ipython --xmode=Plain

In [1]: 1 / 0
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

**`--xmode=Context`**:

```
[ 20:03 jon@hozbox ~/SO/python ]$ ipython --xmode=Context

In [1]: 1 / 0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/jon/SO/python/<ipython console> in <module>()

ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

**`--xmode=Verbose`**:

```
[ 20:01 jon@hozbox ~/SO/python ]$ ipython --xmode=Verbose


In [1]: 1 / 0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/jon/SO/python/<ipython console> in <module>()

ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

---

[Using the Python debugger](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~dock/manuals/IPython/node10.html).

Comment: The second part of your message (--xmode) seems like the answer, but it doesn't seem to work.  I've tried all 3 modenames and the tracebacks all look the same.  Any idea what's causing that?

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, that points out what is presumably an error in (my copy of?) ipython: `$ ipython --xmode=Plain
WARNING: Unrecognized alias: 'xmode', it will probably have no effect.`  However, once in ipython: `In [1]: %xmode
Exception reporting mode: Plain` works fine

Comment: I see. You may need to build a clean copy of ipython (or reinstall using easy_install/pip). As a workaround, you can add that `%mode ...` line as an init command to the ~/.ipython/ config file and problem solved (hopefully)!

Comment: It appears that `--xmode` has become `--InteractiveShell.xmode`. So, to get a full traceback with context and variables, use: `ipython --InteractiveShell.xmode=Verbose script.py`.