# ipython 0.11 exception visible only after exit of pdb

Tags: python, exception, ipython, pdb

both in ipython 0.10 and 0.11 I set the automatic launch of pdb on exceptions.

In ipython 0.10 it works fine:

```
In [1]: 1/0.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/zonca/<ipython console> in <module>()

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
> <ipython console>(1)<module>()

ipdb>
```

instead, in ipython 0.11, the exception is NOT visible:

```
In [1]: 1/0.
> <ipython-input-1-7e0bf5b37da6>(1)<module>()
 -1 1/0.

ipdb>
```

I see it just when I exit the debugger!

```
In [1]: 1/0.
> <ipython-input-1-7e0bf5b37da6>(1)<module>()
     -1 1/0.

ipdb    > 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/zonca/<ipython-input-1-7e0bf5b37da6> in <module>()
----> 1 1/0.

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

In [2]:
```

Anybody else has this issue? I'm on Ubuntu, with python 2.7.2, ipython installed with pip.

Comment: This is the same as my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988864/ipython-debugger-full-traceback-on-interactive-pdb ... glad someone else was frustrated with it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue with IPython 0.11. It will be fixed in 0.12 (which will hopefully be out before Christmas).

Comment: thanks, I was suspecting it, but couldn't find anything on google, do you have a reference to a bug report? I cannot find it either now.